# Word not appearing in the list

Tags: python, list

I have a task where I have a list (german song) and my input is one word in the first half of the song.  The task is to take a word out of the first half of the song, and see if it appears in the second half again, but we have to do it in a specific way. We take the length of the word and jump that many times to word2 and then take length of the word 2 and jump that many times to word3... If I get to the original word again (my input) I stop.

The first problem with my code is that it always goes to the end of the list, it doesn't stop when it reaches the original word (input). The second problem is that it doesn't append word 2 times to the list, it only appends it one time. The loop should break after it reaches the input or the end of the list song.

Here is the code where the problem is(I think): `if song[index] not in found_list:`.

Here is the whole code:

```
song = ["Es", "gingen", "zwei", "Parallelen",
"ins", "Endlose", "hinaus",
"zwei", "kerzengerade", "Seelen",
"und", "aus", "solidem", "Haus",

"Sie", "wollten", "sich", "nicht", "schneiden",
"bis", "an", "ihr", "seliges", "Grab",
"Das", "war", "nun", "einmal", "der", "beiden",
"geheimer", "Stolz", "und", "Stab",

"Doch", "als", "sie", "zehn", "Lichtjahre",
"gewandert", "neben", "sich", "hin", #End of the first half of the song, index: 42
"da", "wards", "dem", "einsamen", "Paare",
"nicht", "irdisch", "mehr", "zu", "Sinn",

"Warn", "sie", "noch", "Parallelen",
"Sie", "wußtens", "selber", "nicht", 
"sie", "flossen", "nur", "wie", "zwei", "Seelen",
"zusammen", "durch", "ewiges", "Licht",

"Das", "ewige", "Licht", "durchdrang", "sie",
"da", "wurden", "sie", "eins", "in", "ihm",
"die", "Ewigkeit", "verschlang", "sie",
"als", "wie", "zwei", "Seraphim"]


originalWord = input("Enter a word: ")
found_list = [] # The list for found words
index = song.index(originalWord) # Get the index of the first instance of "word"
wordCount = song.count(originalWord)


while True:
    if wordCount <= 1:
        print("Word appears only 1 time and therefore can't appear one more time")
        break  
    try:
        if song[index] not in found_list:
            found_list.append(song[index])
            found_list.append(len(song[index]))
        index += len(song[index]) 
    except: 
        break

print(found_list)
```

Comment: What does "take a word out of the first half of the song" and "see if it appears in the second half again" mean exactly? Please use a shorter example and include an expected output.

Comment: This should be the output for word "zwei": ['zwei', 4, 'hinaus', 6, 'solidem', 7, 'bis', 3, 'seliges', 7, 'beiden', 6, 'als', 3, 'Lichtjahre', 10, 'nicht', 5, 'Warn', 4, 'Sie', 3, 'nicht', 5, 'zwei', 4], but the output is the same, only without "zwei" athe the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I just needed to save the input in one variable and then compare if the saved word is in the list...

```
while True:
if wordCount <= 1:
    print("Word appears only 1 time and therefore can't appear one more time")
    break  
try:
    found_list.append(song[index])
    found_list.append(len(song[index]))
    index += len(song[index]) 
    if song[index] == originalWordSaved:
        found_list.append(song[index])
        found_list.append(len(song[index]))
        print("Theorie works")
        break
except:
    print("Theorie doesn't work") 
    break
```